# Trying to target the property that someone clicked on in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm making a Tic-Tac-Toe game with JavaScript and I need to figure out how to target the specific property that was clicked by the player for a function that prevents an overlap of the X, and O.

```
const fillerX = {
    fillX1: document.getElementById('fillerX1'),
    fillX2: document.getElementById('fillerX2'),
    fillX3: document.getElementById('fillerX3'),
    fillX4: document.getElementById('fillerX4'),
    fillX5: document.getElementById('fillerX5'),
    fillX6: document.getElementById('fillerX6'),
    fillX7: document.getElementById('fillerX7'),
    fillX8: document.getElementById('fillerX8'),
    fillX9: document.getElementById('fillerX9')
};

const fillerO = {
    fillO1: document.getElementById('fillerO1'),
    fillO2: document.getElementById('fillerO2'),
    fillO3: document.getElementById('fillerO3'),
    fillO4: document.getElementById('fillerO4'),
    fillO5: document.getElementById('fillerO5'),
    fillO6: document.getElementById('fillerO6'),
    fillO7: document.getElementById('fillerO7'),
    fillO8: document.getElementById('fillerO8'),
    fillO9: document.getElementById('fillerO9')
};


function noLap(){
    if (fillerO.target.style.display="block" || fillerX.target.style.display="block"){
        console.log("it worked!!");
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.target` in your `onclick` function:

```
function clickHandler(event) {
    var clickedBox = event.target; //This will be the thing the user clicked on
    //Do something with clickedBox
}
```

Comment: Alright ill try it out! Also I noticed your always active on my questions, thanks so much you're helping a lot.

Comment: No problem @TheNuthouse, I'm always glad to help.

Comment: Before I accept your answer could you show me how I could integrate that into my code, im having trouble figuring out how to implement it.

Comment: Just add an `onclick` event handler (`yourElement.onclick = clickHandler;`)

Comment: So this is going to be a recursive function?

Comment: Nope - it's just an event handler. Here's a simple example: `<a href="#" onclick="handleEvent(e)">Click Thing</a>` and `function handleEvent(e) { var clicked = e.target; console.log(clicked); }` When you click on the `<a>`, the element will be logged to the console

Comment: I think I understand now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189241/discussion-between-the-nuthouse-and-jack-bashford).